# Compile-abc error in flash pro when publishing to iOS on SDK 3 to 21

Tags: ios, flash, tags

Not sure what the problem is but I keep getting this error

Error creating files.

Stack dump: Compilation failed while executing : compile-abc

THATS IT! no explanation, no solution, searched online and all methods do absolutely nothing, I can remove large chunks of code and sometimes it works, its absolutely random when it works or doesnt work. Sometimes ill remove code and it will work and then I go to publish it again with no changes, AND IT DOESNT WORK!

My code is absolutely fine, it runs and publishes to any other format
Ive been at this for 18 hours and no sleep, Im on a deadline and I have to get this working , this is very serious, Adobe has really gone down hill

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally figured out exactly the cause of the issue.
Apparently packaging to iOS holds a hidden restriction,
functions appear to be limited to the amount of code they can contain.
This is not the case when publishing to anything not iOS related.